# Webview Strange behaviour

Tags: android, webview

I am developing an android app, here i am little confused, firstly, i a loaded a html form data in webview. then navigated to different other pages from the links in my first page. Now coming back to the first page i have use the following code in "onBackPressed()" method. but it shows me empty webview on first page. to avoid that i added another if condition which is written below, but result is still the same,

```
if(webview.canGoBack() == true)
{
    webview.goBack();
    if(!webview.canGoBack())
        webview.loadDataWithBaseURL("http://xyz.com/feed/", data, "text/html", "utf-8", null);
}
// if now on fist page then do the following
else if(activityno==2) {
    Intent fav = new Intent(Views.this, FavroiteShow.class);
    startActivity(fav);
}
//on first page and activity no is not 2 then do the following
else
   finish();
}
```

its like, if webview can go back,simply goback and do nothing else. else if webview cannot go back then check for activity no and go for the code in it, else finish. i want to add one thing to it that if webview has come to the first page. then load my data no matter what the activity no is.

where am i wrong. 
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Try now..

```
 if(webview.canGoBack() == true)
           webview.goBack();
   else  //if there is no history available
         webview.loadDataWithBaseURL("http://xyz.com/feed/", data, "text/html", "utf-8", null);
```

Comment: i couldn't understand your logic... but your inner "if" is no effect at all.. can you little more discriptive

Comment: its like, if webview can go back,simply goback and do nothing else. else if webview cannot go back then check for activity no and go for the code in it, else finish. i want to add one thing to it that if webview has come to the first page. then load my data no matter what the activity no is.

Answer (score 0):

```
@Override
public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    if ((keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK) && webview.canGoBack()) {
        webview.goBack();
        return true;
    } else if (!webview.canGoBack()) {
        webview.loadDataWithBaseURL("http://xyz.com/feed/", data,
                "text/html", "utf-8", null);
        // if now on fist page then do the following
        if (activityno == 2) {
            Intent fav = new Intent(Views.this, FavroiteShow.class);
            startActivity(fav);
        }
        else {
            finish();
        }
    }

    return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);
}
```

I have used overriden Class `onKeyDown`. and Checkes here the KeyEvent.

Hope this Works for you..

Comment: im sory but this did'nt work, now its in loop, showing me the first page then empty then first then empty again and again.

Comment: @RiNxX : Just check the Code, Hope you understand it.

Comment: i tried your code! but as i mentioned it dint work, and i think if i navigate to any page from webview,then press back,this is what happens acc. to your code.. webview.cangoBack()=true, and goes back.but where has it loaded my first page data?it shows me empty webview.